# C# - Analyzing 3 videos at the same time

Tags: c#, foreach

I am using an emotion analytics API that analyzes faces on videos.

My question is, if I have 3 videos in a file, how do I get it to analyze all 3 videos at the same time instead of analyzing one before moving on to the other? I am currently using **foreach** which does the latter:

```
            string[] files1 = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/sit/Videos/9/");

            foreach (string file1 in files1) {

            //API codes

            }
```

What should I use instead of foreach? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`Parallel.ForEach` will get you what you need:

```
Parallel.ForEach(files1, file1 =>
{
   //API code
});
```

Detecting emotion in a video will be a CPU bound operation and depending on your machine, you will most likely see a speedup.